# Find entries in groups where 2 decimal entry's are under 2

Tags: mysql

I would like to check my database for all results where within a group the decimals have at least 2 values under 2.00

select group from table where 2 decimal values in group are under 2

```
Group Decimal
1       1.8
1       1.7
1       1.6
1       2.9
2       3.3
2       2.0       
2       2.9
2       2.9
```

so in the following example group 1 would be returned as atleast 2 decimal numbers are under 2.0

Comment: Considering how few reserved words there are in MySQL, well done for achieving 100% correlation between column names and reserved words.

Comment: Sorry this is not my database headings - I wanted to try and explain my situation as best as I could and using my current headings may have confused matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query, using `HAVING` with a `SUM` (with condition):

```sql
-- condition directly on the SUM
SELECT `Group`
FROM entries
GROUP BY `Group`
HAVING SUM(`Decimal` < 2) > 1;

-- condition with CASE WHEN
SELECT `Group` 
FROM entries
GROUP BY `Group`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `Decimal` < 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2ad73b1f9f01172105cf8f22039a44f)

**Note:** be careful using `group` or `decimal` as column or table names. There are [keywords and reserved words on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) you should avoid using as column and table names. You can use them but have to quote with backticks.

Comment: In MySQL, this can be simplified to `SUM(\`decimal\` < 2) > 1`

Comment: Oh, keep the ANSI standard version too!!